# ionic ion-tab icon with custom image

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here's my [original question on ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-tab-icon-with-custom-img/53154). There has been no responses to it for some time so I thought I could hopefully get some help from here :(

So, my question is really the title. I would like to use my custom image as the icon for ion-tab in my ionic application. I've checked that it works via `ionic serve` by doing it as the following:

`tabs.html`

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-bottom tabs-color-active">
  <!-- this icon does not load -->
  <ion-tab title="LIVE" icon="tab-live energized" href="tab/live">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-live"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="REPLAY" icon="tab-replay energized" href="tab/replay">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-replay"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="SETTINGS" icon="ion-android-options energized" href="tab/setting">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-setting"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

`style.css`

```
...
.tab-live {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-image: url('../img/live.png');
}
.tab-replay {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-image: url('../img/replay.png');
}
```

however, when I run the app on my android device, it says `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` for my `tab-live` and the `tab-live` icon won't load. From what I understand, this error occurs when the app tries to load a certain asset file before it gets loaded in to the memory. But only the `tab-live` image fails to load while all other images loads fine.

If it could be of an issue, the `tab/live` page is what loads when the app starts, and the size of my `live.png` file is about `5.54kb`. I have another image that I use in this `tab/live` page that is larger this image, but it loads fine and I use an `img` tag with `ng-src={{ btnImage }}` to change it around.

So, what could be causing this problem and how could I resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Custom icons for ionic, You can create your class name**

code as bellow...

```
.export-inactive{
    content: url('../img/icons/task-icons/export-inactive.svg'); !important;
}
```

**For example**

```
<div class="tabs tabs-icon-top">
<a class="tab-item">
            <i class="icon export-inactive"></i>
            Export
        </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that file was not found. Either path is wrong or file is not present where you want it to be. Are you sure your image in www/img folder because it's working for me in android.

Comment: Well it's placed in my www/img folder and it displays the image without any issues when I do `ionic serve` and check it on localhost. It occurs only when I run it in my android device. Any guesses on why it won't load?

Comment: Strange. Can you try remove platform and add it again by using following command - 

ionic platform rm android
ionic platform add android

Comment: Well seems like still no luck :S

Comment: Did you check that when you build app image which not display is placed at  platform/assets/www/img/ or not? May be that will be issue.

Comment: oh ummm it's my first app so I don't really know how to check it... are there any links that you possibly could help me out with??

Comment: when you execute command to add platform 'ionic platform add android' and for build app 'ionic build android' platform folder automatically add in root. You can check image there.

Comment: sims like this will help you - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/images-not-displayed-on-android-device/19553/3 specially src="img/John_Williams.jpg" can you tell me exact path of your tabs.html and style.css.

Comment: you mean the platform folder under my app's base folder right? I've checked and it is there just like all other images. I've looked into the link you gave above but I'm curious if that was the problem, then why would all my other images which are in the android assets folder, display without any problem and just this one image not being displayed? :S Could it be due to the android sdk version difference?

Comment: the exact path are `www/templates/tabs.html` and `www/css/style.css`

Comment: Look like every thing is right. can you plz check that image loaded or not by using image tag  
<ion-tab title="LIVE" href="tab/live">
    <img src="./img/live.png" height="50" width="50">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-live"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-tab>

Comment: When I do that, the img will hide behind my header but when I hide the header, it shows up, so I guess it's not about the image?

Comment: OK.. so you should try different way to set image/

Comment: yeah but it's just so strange how I set both my `.tab-live` and `.tab-replay` and only my `.tab-live` gets messed up on my device and `.tab-replay` works just fine. What's more, both work fine on `ionic serve` hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file name & extension of image file.
when you test app with "ionic serve" it's case insensitive but on Android device case sensitive is important.

For example:
change "myicon.PNG" to "myicon.png"

Answer (score 0):

I had been working on implementing the same functionality and faced similar issues. Here's my [actual reply on Ionic Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-tab-icon-with-custom-img/53154/3)
I do not know if the problem still exists but maybe my answer would help devs who might come across this.
So, here’s how to nail it:

```css
/* In tabs.scss: */

// CSS for Settings icon.
    .ion-ios-settings, .ion-md-settings {
        content: url(../assets/icon/cutom-selected-icon.svg);
        width: 24px;
    }
    .ion-ios-settings-outline {
        content: url(../assets/icon/cutom-unselected-icon.svg);
        width: 24px;
    }
    .ion-md-settings[ng-reflect-is-active=false]{
        content: url(../assets/icon/cutom-unselected-icon.svg);
        width: 24px;
    }
```

```html
<!-- In tabs.html: -->

<ion-tabs  [selectedIndex]="indexselected" >
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Settings" tabIcon="settings"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="abc" tabIcon="abc"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="xyz" tabIcon="xyz"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with SCSS as follow.

SCSS file

```
// custom icons
ion-icon {
    &[class*="custom-"] {
        margin: 0 5px 0 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        $sz: 20px;
        width: $sz;
        height: $sz;
    }
    //in case of active
    &[class*="home"][ng-reflect-is-active="true"] {
        background: url("../assets/imgs/home_active.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
        background-size: contain;
    }
    //in case of inactive
    &[class*="home"][ng-reflect-is-active="false"] {
        background: url("../assets/imgs/home_inactive.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
        background-size: contain;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<ion-tab [root]="home" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="custom-chat"></ion-tab>
```