# How to use png`s as icons in ionic tabs instead of svg / existent ionic svg`s?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have Googled a lot and so far have found no solution.

I have a tabs page:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="HomeTab" tabTitle="Home" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="RecentTab" tabTitle="Recents"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="FavTab" tabTitle="Favorites"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="PersonalTab" tabTitle="Personal"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="InfoTab" tabTitle="Information"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Using one of the implemented svg icons of ionic works fine and adds the icon above the text: [Home-Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQuwD.png)

`<ion-tab [root]="HomeTab" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>`

However, I still have not figured out how to use a PNG as an icon. Most tutorials around the web seem to circle around custom SVGs, however none about using PNG's / JPEG.

What is my mistake? Is there a better solution?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: where you are passing the image?

Comment: I am a beginner and dont understand your questions. However: My plan was to have a folder with all the icons: src/app/assets/iconPNG. From there it would pull the PNG

Comment: you can see this answer if it helps -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518232/ionic-ion-tab-icon-with-custom-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution that worked for me:

in the SASS / scss file i select the button i want to edit and then override it with the pathe where my png comes from:

```
.ion-md-home {
content: url("../assets/img/PATH.png") !important; }
```

Then add formating how you need it.

Comment: so this worked for me in V3, have you figured out how to do this in V4?

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way. I think more elegantly:

To HTML template I add an empty img elements with one css class specified

```
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button tab="clean">
            <img class="custom-icon-clean-image"/>
            <ion-label>
                Clean
            </ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
        <ion-tab-button tab="dirty">
            <img class="custom-icon-dirty-image"/>
            <ion-label>
                Dirty
            </ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
```

And to scss file I add img behavior for route activation this way:

```
.custom-icon-clean-image {
  content:url("../../assets/icon/barrel_outline.png");
}

ion-tab-button.tab-selected .custom-icon-clean-image {
  content:url("../../assets/icon/barrel_outline_active.png");
}
```

Solution works with ionic 5 also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom classes to do this.

On the ion-tab directive set the css class to use via icon-on/icon-off.

```
<ion-tab title="Home" icon-on="home" icon-off="home">
```

Add the css class with background image.

```
.tabs .tab-item .icon.home {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('your imagelink here');
  background-size:contain;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me what exactly you are overriding? I implemented it like you suggested however it still doesnt work. Question 1: .icon.home: is home the name of the htm page, or the name we are overriding? Question 2: Is it possible to check if my imagelink / path is correct?

Comment: you are kust adding a css class and attaching that to the tab. your css class have the image icon

Comment: I am sorry, but the icon is not appearing. I took the steps you wrote precisely but its still wrong